# Typed parameters in Create Instance dialog

Tags: visual-studio-2005

I am using Visual Studio 2005 Team Edition and am attempting to instantiate a class using the Create Instance option in the Class View. The constructor has three parameters, two of which are DateTime structures.

My question is: how do I enter a valid DateTime into the `Value` box?

I have tried the following to no avail:

```
28-05-2009 06:00:00
"28-05-2009 06:00:00"
new DateTime("28-05-2009 06:00:00")
new System.DateTime("28-05-2009 06:00:00")
```

In all cases it just shows a `Type Mismatch: 'System.DateTime' expected` error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's currently not possible in the existing Object Test Bench

See this link. It's currently an "On Hold" Feature Request

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=113080

Comment: Blow! Cheers for that. What a wasted opportunity by MS. Those are the sort of things Borland always got right as I remember.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new DateTime instance from Class View, and select it from the dropdown list in the grid.